# installing media player problem

Tags: command-line

it's my 1st exposure to Ubuntu, been trying to install music and video players using terminal and Ubuntu software but none of them works, been trying to search on Google for apps like vlc for Ubuntu but the ones I've been downloading cant even install...help please.

Ofcourse there are default media players like rhythmbox and the default video player but they are not functioning in my PC, they pop up a message asking for plug ins

Comment: What command are you using or what error is being shown to you by your machine?

Comment: sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: that is for vlc

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily sudo apt update sudo apt install vlc

Comment: Try this for vlc if any other multimedia apps are refusing to get installed then I would recommend to reinstall Ubuntu, and during reinstallation check "Install media player codecs or third party apps" I hope your issue will be fixed after this

Comment: You can and should install additional codecs and for that you don't need to reinstall the full system. Just do `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: the command did not work....sad.

Comment: could it be because am using an older version of ubuntu?? am using Ubuntu 16.10  32bit.